# Image getting resized after download in tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

I am getting an image from a URL in a tableview cell. The image view is hugging the right top and bottom of a cell in the tableview cell. To the left of the image is text. I want the text to set the height of the tableview cell automatically and I want the image to conform to the size that is set by the text. How would I do that? Right now it is working but when the image is being downloaded, the cell resizes to become much larger because it uses the large dimensions of the image. As a result the cell in the tableview gets really tall. How would I fix this?

I know the issue is because I am using a greater than or equal to constraint between two of my labels as you can see below in the screenshot. But I need that greater than or equal to constraint.

Here is what my constraints look like:

[image]

This is what they look like and what I want it to look like: 
[image][image]

Comment: Set the image view height to be equal to the height of the text?

Comment: I tried that and it still expands. I tried setting the top of the image view to match the top of the highest text and the bottom of the image view to match the bottom of the text and the same issue happened

Comment: I changed the inequality constraint to a constant constraint and I am still having the same issue. I also tried putting all the labels in a view and then setting that view equal to the height of the image view and that did not solve it. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: That makes sense and that is why I got rid of the inequality. But the issue is still there. I want the labels to be the determining factor for the height of the cell. The way I have it setup, I had to set one of the labels to have a lower content hugging priority than the others. The image view still has the lowest content hugging priority but I don't think that matters here. Is it possible to set the hight primarily using the labels? and have the image view conform to the size of the labels?

Comment: that is exactly what I have but the image view still keep expanding the cell once the image is downloaded. I am using kingfisher to download the image if that makes any difference. I have added a new image with what my constraints look like

Comment: By the way, if you want to know _why_ your cell gets sized the way it does based on whatever the constraints are that you have, use the View Debugger to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set your constraints for the 3 labels, now for the image view set *equal height* to your cell(90-95% should do it). So the labels control the height of the cell and then the cell controls the height of the image view.

Edit: I think that you are complicating things. All your cells will have the same height(title,preview, source of 3,4,1 lines respectively), let them set the height, you don't need content hugging priority with the way i am suggesting.
I would use equal widths to set the width for all the items in your cell, the i would set the horizontal centers, for the spacing between constraints you can either use top-bottom constraints or set vertical centers and you are done.

Bare in mind that top-bottom-trailing-leading are NOT always the best choice, sometimes (like this one) can cause headache.

Comment: the labels aren't controlling the height of the cell because I am changing the content hugging priority of one of the labels in the cell to stop the error. am I not supposed to do that?

Comment: No the cells might not have the same height. I have set the lines to 3,4,1 lines respectively in the storyboard but that does not necessarily mean that each label will have enough text in it to fill all the lines. I want the labels to set the height based off how much text is in the label. From what I have experienced, as soon as you have UILabels in a cell that set the height of the cell, one of the labels needs to have a lower content hugging priority. I centered the image view on the right vertically within the container

Comment: The source will be 1 line, the preview will be 4 unless you have whole article with less than 4  lines?? So the only chance is that the title will be less than 3, worse case scenario 2? Now for 1 line is it worth to spoil the uniformity of the tableView?

Comment: Irrespectively of what priorities you set for the labels they will end up giving the cell an X height value, by setting the image view to be 95% equal height of X you will be good.

Comment: I see from your comment to matt that my answer fixed your problem, please consider accepting it .

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a cell that is laid out more or less as you desire:

[image]

The first label has three lines. The second label has four lines. The third label has one line. The first label has a leading constraint and a trailing constraint to the cell content view; the other two labels have their leading and trailing edges aligned to it. There are four constraints from top to bottom, content view to first label to second label to third label to content view.

The image view has its top aligned to the first label top, its bottom aligned to the third label bottom, its leading edge constrained to the first label trailing edge, and its trailing edge constrained to the content view.

That's all.

**EDIT** Sorry, I omitted a piece of the puzzle. For your use case, the image view's vertical content compression resistance would need to be lower than any label's vertical hugging priority. That says: "Let the labels dictate how tall I can be." Your labels have a vertical hugging priority of 251, so 250 would do.

[image]

Comment: I am literally doing exactly the same thing and for some reason it does not work. I am even using a static image not downloading it. You must be adjusting the content hugging priority of one of the labels right?

Comment: now what @do2 said worked. When I set the height of the image view equal to the height of the cell, that fixed the problem

Comment: if I don't adjust them the storyboard gives me an error how do I get rid of the error?

Comment: Ignore it. The storyboard doesn't understand about self-sizing cells. There's no issue at runtime. [I think you could silence the warning by turning the bottom-most constraint into a `>=` inequality, but I didn't bother.]

Comment: even if I ignore the warning, it still doesn't solve the issue like the solution that @Do2 gave did

Comment: It will really bother me if I don't figure this out especially after you have taken so much time to help. Really appreciate that by the way! So I created a very basic sample project that I publish here: https://github.com/nevinjethmalani/test. Do you mind telling me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I just pushed an update as well if you have already looked at it

Comment: Sorry this took so long. You were right: for your use case, it's just a matter of tweaking the image view's vertical content compression resistance priority. Your github example project then behaves exactly as you would wish.

Comment: no problem at all! how were you able to get the desired result by tweaking the image view's vertical content compression resistance priority? I tried so many tweaks of the image views's compressions resistance and nothing worked. I included a bunch of different commits with different methods I tried. The only way I was able to get it to work was by setting the image view height equal to the height of my cell. If there is a better way, I would love to know.

Comment: See my edited answer, which should clarify. If you like, I'll do a pull request on your github project that implements the fix.

Comment: YES! Finally got it. Thanks a lot! I also pushed it to the github repo so anybody else trying the same thing can see it.